# oracle 11g which have data type `TIMESTAMP(6) with Local Time Zone` archived different data in windows and linux in csv

Tags: java, linux, windows, oracle, timestamp

I have column in oracle 11g which have data type `TIMESTAMP(6) with Local Time Zone` and the data in it are

> 01-JAN-03 02.00.00.000000000 AM
>
> 07-APR-16 12.32.32.996000000 PM
>
> 02-MAY-16 12.06.42.219000000 PM
>
> 02-MAY-16 03.03.20.796000000 PM

When I archived this data in Windows by using this code -

```
    TIMESTAMPLTZ columnValue = (TIMESTAMPLTZ) row.getValues()[pos];
     String timestamp = columnValue.toString(connection, columnValue.getBytes());

    public static String toString(Connection var0, byte[] var1) throws SQLException {
            return toString(var0, var1, (Calendar)null);
        }
 public static String toString(Connection var0, byte[] var1, Calendar var2) throws SQLException {
        Calendar var3 = toCalendar(var0, (Calendar)null, var1, var2);
        int var4 = var3.get(1);
        int var5 = var3.get(2) + 1;
        int var6 = var3.get(5);
        int var7 = var3.get(11);
        int var8 = var3.get(12);
        int var9 = var3.get(13);
        int var10 = -1;
        if(var1.length == SIZE_TIMESTAMPLTZ) {
            var10 = TIMESTAMP.getNanos(var1, 7);
        }

        return TIMESTAMPTZ.toString(var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var3.getTimeZone().getID());
    }
```

Here toString() function is of TIMESTAMPLTZ class. And I am using metamodal to archived data. The archived data in csv file in `WINDOWS` is shows like -

> 2003-01-01 02:00:00 Asia/Calcutta
>
> 2016-04-07 12:32:32.996 Asia/Calcutta
>
> 2016-05-02 12:06:42.219 Asia/Calcutta
>
> 2016-05-02 15:03:20.796 Asia/Calcutta

And with same code I am archive same data in `LINUX`. The csv file shows data like -

> 2002-12-31 20:30:00 GMT
>
> 2016-04-07 07:02:32.996 GMT
>
> 2016-05-02 06:36:42.219 GMT
>
> 2016-05-02 09:33:20.796 GMT

What can I do in Linux to get same csv data as in windows?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When I execute `columnValue.toString();` statement my colvalue.getBytes() are `120,116,4,7,8,3,33,59,93,-63,0` in both linux and windows, I get `2016-04-07 12:32:32.996 Asia/Calcutta` result in windows and with same value I get `2016-04-07 07:02:32.996 GMT` result in linux.
What can I do to get same result in linux as windows.

Answer (score 1):

Datatype `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` means the time is **always** (and only) shown in your local timezone. Thus you cannot modify the output timezone of it.

In order to get it in "Asia/Calcutta" you can either

1. Change your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` before you execute the query, i.e. by

   `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';`
2. Set `Asia/Calcutta` time zone environment at your computer before you connect to database, i.e. `export ORA_SDTZ=Asia/Calcutta`
3. Cast the value to `TIMEZONE` and then convert it to 'Asia/Calcutta', i.e.

   `TO_CHAR((CAST(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr')`

Comment: Corrected typo in answer